# list view builder with hive database

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, flutter-hive

I was using a list view builder which got its item count from the hive database. I managed to get it to work but its text appeared to be in brackets for example (Apollo, Jesus) any ideas on how to fix it. as in the formatting so it would appear as apollo,jesus. FYI I opened and initiated the box on the main.dart page

here is my code, I'm still learning sorry for bad code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';
import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(nextpage());
}

class nextpage extends StatefulWidget {
  const nextpage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<nextpage> createState() => _nextpageState();
}

class _nextpageState extends State<nextpage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            leading: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.chevron_left,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
              onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
            ),
            backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,
            centerTitle: true,
            title: Text(
              'Database',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
            ),
          ),
          backgroundColor: Colors.yellow[200],
          body: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: Hive.box('db').length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return Container(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Text(
                        Hive.box('db').values.toString(),
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
I tried changing the text to Hive.box('db').values.toString but it didn't provide results
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to open the box to receive data. You can do

```dart
void main() async {
  await Hive.openBox('db');
  runApp(nextpage());
}
```

or use [`FutureBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) [`.open()` is a future method] before `ListView`.

More about using [hivedb](https://docs.hivedb.dev/)

Comment: i already did its just on the main.dart file

Comment: it should solve the issue then. make sure to make it async method and wait